# Google Maps API KML Styling Not Showing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon, kml, styling

I've defined a KML layer for my Maps API mashup. The boundary poly is showing up fine, but I can't get it to honor the styling. Any idea why it's not picking up on my Styles element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

<Document>

<Style id="defaultStyles">
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>7dff0000</color>
    </PolyStyle>
    <LineStyle>
      <width>3</width>
    </LineStyle>        
</Style>


<Placemark id="myBoundary">
    <name>Boundary</name>
    <styleUrl>#defaultStyles</styleUrl>

    <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>-0.981550665136288,52.204573365561728 .... 
        </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>

</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: @geocodezip - Coords list is abbreviated for simplification. Exceeds the max char count with full list. KML validates fine and the Poly renders. Just the styling isn't being picked up on. Complete KML is here http://new.bugbrooke-village.co.uk/assets/kml/bugbrooke-boundary.kml

Comment: The styling on that KML is working for me:  [link](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://new.bugbrooke-village.co.uk/assets/kml/bugbrooke-boundary.kml) (unless you are not expecting purple, the style there is different from your post `<color>7dff017f</color>`)

Comment: So odd. Should be hot pink ff017f (purple). In your link (for me) I still see red? I've dumped cache and still the same.  http://new.bugbrooke-village.co.uk/assets/images/screendump.JPG

Comment: I see purple.  It is possible that the KML is being cached by Google's servers (has it changed?).  Add a query parameter to the URL to bust the cache.  (http://new.bugbrooke-village.co.uk/assets/kml/bugbrooke-boundary.kml?a=0) You are probably going through a different Google data center than I am.  You could also see if [my copy of your KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/bugbrooke-boundary.kml) gives you different results.

Comment: OK; yeah. Google caching. Added query and all good. I'll add some code to append random QS to end of KML source whilst I'm working on the styling. Bloody annoying. Cheers for working through this with me LOL!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The KML is being cached by Google's servers.  Add a query parameter to the URL to bust the cache. (http://new.bugbrooke-village.co.uk/assets/kml/bugbrooke-boundary.kml?a=0)